# AngularJS - show popup card-list?

Tags: angularjs, popup, ionic-framework

I'm using `Ionic` framework to develop an app and have a view as the image shown below and I want a popup card-list to appear when the user taps on the textfields `Account No:` and `Destination A/C:`, the card-list is to be populated using a call to a web-service.

I'm a newbie to `AngularJS` and would appreciate if you could help me out with a basic example to get this done.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh4n6.png

**fundtransfer.html**

```
 <div class="list" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">


          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
              Fund Transfer
            </h3>
          </div>


        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Account No:</span>
                <input type="text" id="accNo" name="accNo" ng-model="accNo" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" placeholder="Account No:">
                    </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Destination A/C:</span>
                <input type="text" id="desAccNo" name="desAccNo" ng-model="desAccNo" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" placeholder="Destination A/C:">
                    </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Amount</span>
                <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" ng-model="amount" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" placeholder="Amount:">
                    </label>
        </div>


             <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="submit()">Transfer</a>

          </div>
```

Comment: Might I suggest the official AngularJS tutorial? It's pretty good. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: When you say 'popup card list' do you maybe mean an Ionic Modal view opening that contains a list of cards?

Comment: @JeremyWilken Yes. I used an Ionic Modal view to get it done, but it takes up the whole window. Any idea how to get it to the center, like in popups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Ionic modal component, and override the CSS to resize if you don't want it to be full screen. It just takes a little CSS to resize the modal window, and then you can put the card component inside of the modal.

**Markup**

```
<ion-modal-view class="modal slide-in-up ng-enter active ng-enter-active">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="card">
    ...
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  min-height: 60%; 
  background: none;
}
```